# Discriminant of a quadratic form over a field $k$ is in $k^*/(k^*)^2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, quadratic-forms

Give a quadratic form $f=a_1X_1^2+a_2X_2^2+...+a_nX_n^2$ over a field $k$, with $d(f)$ being the discriminant of $f$.
I read in *Serre's - A course in arithmetic* that $d(f)\in k^*/(k^*)^2$.
(In page 35, he specifically refers to $k=\mathbb Q_p$)

Why is that?
Is it because $d(f)=a_1\cdot a_2\cdot ...\cdot a_n$ and he's assuming $a_i\in k^*/(k^*)^2$ $\forall 1\leq i\leq n$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point is that this formula for $f$ is not unique (up to isometry). You can do base changes that transform it into $f = b_1X_1^2+\dots +b_nX_n^2$. So if you want the discriminant to depend only on the isometry class of $f$, and not on a specific choice of basis, $d(f)=a_1\cdots a_n$ cannot work, because in general $a_1\cdots a_n\neq b_1\cdots b_n$.

On the other hand, it is not hard to check that $a_1\cdots a_n$ and $b_1\cdots b_n$ are the same up to a square, so they are congruent modulo $(k^*)^2$, and $d(f)=a_1\cdots a_n$ is well-defined, not as an element of $k$, but of $k^*/(k^*)^2$.

Comment: Thanks. Let me see if I get it: $d(f)$ is useful to us when it is not dependent on the basis. You claim that $a_1...a_n$ equals to $b_1...b_n$ up to squares and hence it is sufficient to define $d(f)$ as though it's in  $k^*/(k^*)^2$. If I'm correct, how do you prove  $a_1...a_n$ equals to $b_1...b_n$ up to squares?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong: if $A'=XAX^t$ then $\det(A')=\det(A) \det(X)^2$.
And that proves it. Is that what you meant?

Comment: Yes, that's about it.